# Characterization of Compactness in $\ell^\infty$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

The metric space $\ell^\infty$ consists of all bounded real valued sequences with the metric is $ d(x,y) = \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} | \xi_i - \eta_i | $, where $x = (\xi_i), y = (\eta_i)$. I have been wondering about compactness in this space. I know that this space is isometric with $C(\beta \mathbb{N})$ and so compactness in $\ell^\infty$ comes down to the Arzela-Ascoli theorem in $C(\beta \mathbb{N})$. However, I barely understand what a continuous function is on $\beta \mathbb{N}$, and so I'm nowhere near understanding what equicontinuity would be. Besides, I am more interested in what equicontinuity in $C(\beta \mathbb{N})$ would mean for the corresponding sequences in $\ell^\infty$.

So my question is this:
What is a characterization of compactness in $\ell^\infty$ which only concerns itself with conditions on the sequences? In other words, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions to place on a family of sequences in $\ell^\infty$ to ensure the family is compact?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this one helps you but since $\ell^{\infty}$ is complete if you take a compact $K\subset \ell^{\infty}$ then $K$ is closed and totally bounded. Conversly , if you take $K\subset \ell^{\infty}$ closed and totally bounded , since $\ell^{\infty}$ is complete metric space it follows that $K$ is also complete, hence $K$ is complete and totally bounded hence compact.

So the question comes down to whether a closed subset $K$ of $\ell^{\infty}$ is totally bounded.

The same applies in $C_{0}$ then there is a characterisation of $K\subset C_0 $ closed and totally bounded $\Longleftrightarrow$ for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist $n_{0} \in \Bbb N$ such that for every $x=(\xi_{k})\in K$ and for every $k\geq n_{0}$ then $|\xi_{k}|\leq \epsilon.$

Its intresting if there is any similar for the $\ell^{\infty}$.

I hope these thoughts will help you to tackle the problem , if you find anything let me know !

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to write the elements of $\ell_\infty$ as *functions* instead of sequences, to nicify the notation.

One characterization of compactness is this:

> > $S\subset\ell_\infty$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded and has the following property: If $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $S$ and $f_n(j)\to f(j)$ for every $j$ then $||f_n-f||\to0$.

Suppose $S$ satisfies those three conditions and $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $S$. Then there is a subsequence, which I'm going to write as $(g_n)$, such that $g_n(j)\to g(j)$ for every $j$. Since $S$ is bounded, $g\in\ell_\infty$, and the hypothesis shows that $||g_n-g||\to0$. So $(f_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Conversely, suppose $S$ is compact, $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $S$ and $f_n(j)\to f(j)$ for every $j$. In general in a compact metric space if $x\not\to  x$ then $(x_n)$ has a subsequence converging to $y\ne x$. But clearly no subsequence of $(f_n)$ can converge to anything but $f$; hence $f_n\to f$.

You could make that proof look fancier by involing Banach-Alaoglu. Note that the unit ball of $\ell_\infty$ is weak* metrizable, since $\ell_1$ is separable. And note that if $||f_n||_\infty\le 1$ then $f_n\to f$ weak* if and only if $f_n(j)\to f(j)$ for every $j$. So the result says that $S$ is compact if and only if $S$ is closed and bounded and the identity map on $S$ is weak*-to-norm continuous.

**Edit:** The rest of this is wrong. The error is that a norm-closed set need not be weak* closed. Leaving it here instead of deleting it  in case anyone wants to try to fix it. (I believe it's correct for *convex* sets...)

Hmm, just noticed that that works in any measure space, or at least any measure space such that $(L^1)^*=L^\infty$:

> > In any such measure space, $S\subset L^\infty$ is compact if and only if $S$ is closed and bounded and the identity map on $S$ is weak*-to-norm continuous.

Proof: One direction is obvious, since if $S$ is closed and bounded it is weak* compact.

Suppose $S$ is compact. Then $S$ is certainly closed and bounded. The identity map on $L^\infty$ is norm-to-weak* continuous. Hence standard compact-Hausdorff-automatic-continuity-of-the-inverse magic shows that the identity map from $S$ with the norm topology to $S$ with the weak* topology is a homeomorphism.

Not that it's clear whether that weak*-to-norm continuity holds in a given example - I'm not claiming any of this is actually useful...